# Remove extra space from Grid

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts, padding

I am trying to make a figure with four plots using Grid[]. I added some padding to accommodate the FrameLabels but I would like to remove only the right padding and yet keep the four Plots with the same size.

Code:

```
imgpad = {{60, 60}, {60, 10}};
figa = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> imgpad];
figb = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> imgpad];
figc = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> imgpad];
figd = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> imgpad];
grid = Grid[{{figa, figb}, {figc, figd}}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

If I change the imgpag to {{60, 10}, {60, 10}}, the space in the middle is also removed, which I don't want. How can I remove only the space on the right without changing the size of the plots?

Edit: These are the correct paddings. I need them to be exactly like this, but the plots need to be the same size.

Code:

```
figa=Plot[x,{x,0,10},ImageSize->500,ImagePadding->{{60,60},{60,10}}];
figb=Plot[x,{x,0,10},ImageSize->500,ImagePadding->{{60,10},{60,10}}];
figc=Plot[x,{x,0,10},ImageSize->500,ImagePadding->{{60,60},{60,10}}];
figd=Plot[x,{x,0,10},ImageSize->500,ImagePadding->{{60,10},{60,10}}];
grid=Grid[{{figa,figb},{figc,figd}},Spacings->0]
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2:** Use the form `ImageSize -> 1 -> 50` for setting image size:

```
figa = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, ImagePadding -> {{60, 60}, {60, 10}}];
figb = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, ImagePadding -> {{60, 10}, {60, 10}}];
figc = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, ImagePadding -> {{60, 60}, {60, 10}}];
figd = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, ImagePadding -> {{60, 10}, {60, 10}}];

grid = Grid[{{figa, figb}, {figc, figd}}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
imgpad = {{60, 10}, {60, 10}};
ClearAll[figa, figb, figc, figd]
figa = figb = figc = figd = 
     Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, ImagePadding -> imgpad];

Framed @ Grid[
  MapAt[Replace[#, HoldPattern[ImagePadding -> p_] :> 
      ImagePadding -> (p + {{50, 0}, {0, 0}}), All] &,
       {{figa, figb}, {figc, figd}}, {All, 2}], 
  Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
imgpad = {{60, 10}, {60, 10}};

figa = figb = figc = figd = 
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> imgpad];

Framed @ Grid[{{figa, figb}, {figc, figd}}, Spacings -> {5, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. The space in the middle is there, but it crops the extra FrameLabel that I need to add to the graphs on the left. Maybe you could crop the right space after the complete image is generated?

Comment: @Rodrigo, please see the update.

Comment: The padding {{60, 60}, {60, 10}} is required for figa and figc, while for figb and figd is {{60, 10}, {60, 10}}. I am adding an extra axis on the right side of figa and figc so I need that extra padding. The problem is if I set different paddings, the plots change sizes. Your update is almost correct, but it still crops the right side of figa and figc.

Comment: @Rodrigo, it would help a lot if you updated your question with a more detailed example.

Comment: I added more details. Basically I need that padding and the plots need to be the same size.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. Cropped the right extra space after the Grid is generated :)

Code:

```
imgpad={{60,60},{60,10}};
cropGraphics[g_,x_,y_,w_,h_]:=Graphics[Inset[g,{x,y},{0,0}],PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,1}},ImageSize->{w,h},AspectRatio->Full]
figa=Plot[x,{x,0,10},ImageSize->500,ImagePadding->imgpad];
figb=Plot[x,{x,0,10},ImageSize->500,ImagePadding->imgpad];
figc=Plot[x,{x,0,10},ImageSize->500,ImagePadding->imgpad];
figd=Plot[x,{x,0,10},ImageSize->500,ImagePadding->imgpad];
grid=Grid[{{figa,figb},{figc,figd}},Spacings->0];
cropGraphics[grid,0.525,0.5,950,617]
```

[image]